# Does Ruby treat variables assigned an array differently than variables assigned a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I thought that when you declare a variable and assign it a string or an array, you are making an independent copy of that string or array. Further, that whatever you do to that variable doesn't affect the original. My assumption does not hold true with the first set of code below:

```
array = ["tubular", "bell", "single", "file"]
word = array[0]
word[0] = word[0].upcase 
array.join(" ") # => Tubular bell single file
word            # => Tubular
array[0]        # => Tubular
```

but it does with the second:

```
string = "ten aviators climbing isoceles"
word = string[0]
word = word.upcase 
string    # => ten aviators climbing isoceles
word      # => T
string[0] # => t
```

Could someone explain why in the first set of code, setting `word[0]` to `word[0].upcase` results in a change to the array `bell_arr` I originally assigned to the variable `word`, but a similar change does not take place with a variable assigned a string as in the second set of code?

Answer (score 2):

This is has to deal with what we call mutability/immutability and object references in programming languages. A few searches with "Ruby" and "immutability", "references" would bring a few good results but basically

```
array = ["tubular bell single", "bell", "single", "file"]
```

An array holds references to some Ruby Objects, here `String` instances. A "Ruby string" is actually an instance of the class String. Your array contains references to some instances of String.

```
sentence = array[0] # Ruby terminal shows "tubular bell single"
# But actually, array[0] is a reference to a Ruby Object
```

Array[0] is a reference to a string Object, ie. array[0] is like a pointer to a string. But when you call `array[0]` in your Ruby terminal, you are actually just interested in the string representation, not the object itself, so Ruby, behind the scene, calls something like array[0].to_string so you can see the string and not just something like `#<Object:0x000000031082b0>`, which is what Ruby usually shows when you write in your terminal a reference to an object and press enter.

Now unlike other programming languages (like C), there is nothing "below" a String class, there is no "Character" class. A String instance isn't made of references to other Ruby objects.

When you are calling "sentence[0]", that basically means you want the first letter of the sentence as a Ruby Object that you can manipulate. So it does create a new Object in the memory.

So actually `first_letter = sentence[0]` creates a **new** String instance, which is just the string containg "t"

However, when you call sentence[0] = "t", you are calling a specific method on the String instance, which basically says : replace this letter by this one. When doing this, you are modifying the instance itself !

EDIT : maybe the following will make it clear. Ruby uses "object identifiers" to identify the instances of each Object

```
a = "Hello World"
b = "Hello again"
c = "Hello World" # Same string representation as a

a.object_id # 26817860
b.object_id # 25401040
c.object_id # 25247200 # Note it's not the same number as a!

array = [a, b, c]

array[0].object_id # 26817860, so it's the instance of a !!

first_letter = a[0]  # Ruby shows "H"
first_letter.object_id # 23178100, a different object in memory
```

Now

```
a = "A new string"
a.object_id # 24367200, it's again new object in memory
array # ["Hello World", "Hello again", "Hello World"]
array[0].object_id # 26817860, our array[0] still points to the original object_id
```

But

```
first_item = array[0] # "Hello World"
first_item.object_id # 26817860 alright, no magic trick, this is still the object_id of "a"
first_item[0] = "X"
first_item.object_id # 26817860 UNCHANGED ! We have really changed our instance and not created a new one !
array # ["Xello World", "Hello again", "Hello World"]
```

Comment: "But, in order to represent this, you need to make a new String instance"--This is not the reason for the difference. I interpret that by "something like ... `to_string`", you are mentioning the inspection string created by `p`. Those strings are newly created in either of the two cases, every time they are printed, and that is irrelevant for the issue in question.

Comment: @CyrilDD when you say "But when you call array[0] in your Ruby terminal", would an example of that be writing    puts(array[0]    ?

Comment: What I mean is that your array in memory is an array of pointers, `array = [pointer_to_26817860, pointer_to_25401040, pointer_to_25247200]`. Thus calling `array[0]` should return the object whose id is 25247200. Usually Ruby shows something like `#<Object:0x000000031082b0>` (try typing a = Object.new), but when the Object is a String, it just returns its string representation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `word = string[0]` creates a new string instance. If a single character taken out of a string is the same string instance as the original string, then that would mean that the content of the original string has been replaced by that single character. That would be too inconvenient. Ruby's `String#[]` does not do that. It creates a new string instance. And furthermore, `word = word.upcase` is just a variable assignment. It uses the old `word` and creates a new variable `word`. It does not do anything to the old `word` (which is not the same as `string` in the first place).